# Rust. Closures and move

Tags: rust, move

Читая главу [Closures: Anonymous Functions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html) возник вопрос на который пока не смог найти ответ.
Есть небольшой код:

```
fn main() {
    let mut count = 0;
    let mut next = move || {
        count += 1;
        count
    };

    println!("{}", next()); // 1
    println!("{}", next()); // 2

    println!("{}", count);  // 0

    println!("{}", next()); // 3
}
```

Мне не очень понятен механизм выполнения этого кода. Почему после первых двух вызовов `next`, `count` остаётся равным `0`? Хотелось бы услышать как это работает на самом деле. Спасибо!

Comment: целые числа - копируются, потому что они реализуют типаж Copy. Поэтому, внутри замыкания будет свое count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ключевое слово `move` перед замыканием означает, что захват окружения (переменной `count` в данном случае) произойдет при помощи перемещения (передачи владения). Но `count` является примитивным целым числом, так что для него реализован маркерный типаж [Copy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html), из-за чего `count` просто копируется внутрь замыкания, т.е. у нас получаются два независимых значения: тот `count`, что был объявлен в `main`, который никто не меняет, и его дубликат, который живет внутри замыкания и меняется при вызовах.